# Why prepended and appended comments are not shown in PostgreSQL query log?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6.12 and want to log all queries. After researching on how to do that i've updated `postgresql.conf` file and restarted postgres:

```
logging_collector = on
log_directory = 'pg_log'
log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log'
log_min_error_statement = error
log_min_duration_statement = 0
```

It works fine and there are logged queries in `/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_log/postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log`, but when I add a comment at the beginning or at the end of query it's not show in log file.

Sample query:

```
/* This comment is not shown in logs */ SELECT * FROM example;
```

Comments are shown in logs only when they are inserted in the middle of query:

```
SELECT * FROM /* This comment is shown in logs */ example;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you submitting these queries?  Whatever library you are using to connect to the database may be stripping out the comments before sending them over to database, so the database does not have access to them.  If I submit queries directly with "psql", or with Perl's DBD::Pg, they work as expected.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually what the real issue was. I used Intellij IDEA to execute queries and apparently it strips my comments. With "psql" it worked well